# Css Caption/Text Position

Tags: html, css

Hello can anyone help me out with a positioning problem?
[Here is what I have to work with](http://filehop.org/pkb/artistwebtemplate/images.html)

Okay I would like those titles to be closer to the pictures.

This is the html

```
<li><a href="http://goo.gl/Kt472"><img src="http://dsjvpv76ko1eo.cloudfront.net/uimg/82ac1838e5ac76806ad2f85cf6afa1fe.90x90" alt="Img" /></a></li>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
text-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(27,54,33,0.8);font-weight:normal;color:#4D311E;letter-spacing:4pt;word-spacing:-1pt;font-size:15px;text-align:right;font-family:tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;line-height:0;margin-left: 100px; margin-bottom:150px;
```

Comment: Remove `text-align: right`

Answer (score 2):

Change `text-align:right` to `text-align:left`.

```
#tr_caption {
    text-align:left;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: @DieVers If this solution worked for you, please upvote and/or accept this as the answer. That way others who run into the same problem in the future will know this solution works.